# Cognos Chart with "No Data Available" although list shows data

Tags: charts, cognos

I am completely new to Cognos, so sorry if I don't state some necessary information. I can't go into specifics about my chart, but here is the background:

- I have a SQL code running into my Query
- My chart and list use the same Query and have the exact same fields
- My chart is a basic line graph
- When I change my aggregate function to total for my y-axis, then I can see the data points
- I do not want to use an aggregate function (I need to see all the points for my x and y-axis)
- My x-axis is only one object, but it has multiple y-axis values within a year (which is my series). Ex:[product-cost-year list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFAkI.png),
  where my product is the x-axis, cost is the y-axis, and series is year.

How can I get my chart to appear with all my data points? Eventually, I would like to add an upper and lower confidence interval to this chart. 
 [image]

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this issue is to create another column that simply counts the number of products (1,2,3,...9). We will call this column count. Keep all your fields the same (product for x-axis, cost for y-axis, and year for series). You will want to add count underneath product on the x-axis. You should see your mouse pointer turn to a horizontal line and it will place it under and to the right of product. Make sure not to place it just to the right of product.